# Does the table constraint CHECK gets executed on deletions?

Tags: postgresql, constraint, delete

I guess not but if someone has an idea perhaps could give me a hand.

I'm trying to restrict the deletion of a row of a table under some circumstances that requires to query against other tables.

An example

Each worker (table `worker`) references the physical person (table `person`).
The check aims to allows the existence of workers that will work with his `actual_hapiness_level` (from table `worker`) >= `base_hapiness_level` (from table `person`), so all the underlying persons are *happy*.

There is an important exception, is you hire a worker that **acts a clown**, everybody is happy and therefore the former restrictions doesn't apply. Try to follow the example running one statement at the time, reading the comments.

And the end you will get inconsesty from a "business" point of view.

```
create table person (
    id serial primary key,
    base_hapiness_level int,
    name text
);
create table worker (
    id serial primary key,
    person_id int,
    actual_hapiness_level int,
    acts_as_clown bool default false,
    CONSTRAINT person_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
          REFERENCES person (id) MATCH SIMPLE
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_worker_happy_according_to_his_personal_values (bigint,bigint) RETURNS boolean AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Performing things_are_okey(person_id= %,base_hapiness_level= %)', $1, $2;
    RETURN ($2 >= (select p.base_hapiness_level from person p where p.id = $1));
    END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_there_a_clown_in_there_to_handle_the_unhappiness () RETURNS boolean AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Performing is_there_a_clown_in_there_to_handle_the_unhappiness';
    RETURN EXISTS (select * from worker where acts_as_clown is true);
    END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;

ALTER TABLE worker ADD CONSTRAINT person_can_work check (
    is_worker_happy_according_to_his_personal_values(person_id,actual_hapiness_level) OR
    (NOT is_worker_happy_according_to_his_personal_values(person_id,actual_hapiness_level) AND is_there_a_clown_in_there_to_handle_the_unhappiness())
);

-- create 3 persons
insert into person (base_hapiness_level,name) values (50,'robert');
insert into person (base_hapiness_level,name) values (10,'cris');
insert into person (base_hapiness_level,name) values (0,'the_clown');

-- insertion 1 is okey, as there is no clow required to the hapiness level of robert
insert into worker (actual_hapiness_level,person_id) values (50,(select id from person where name = 'robert'));

-- insertion 2 goes wrong, as there is no clown to handle the unhapiness of crish
insert into worker (actual_hapiness_level,person_id) values (1,(select id from person where name = 'cris'));

-- let's hire a clown.....
insert into worker (actual_hapiness_level,person_id,acts_as_clown) values (100,(select id from person where name = 'the_clown'),true);

-- try to insert cris again (with the clown is alright)
insert into worker (actual_hapiness_level,person_id) values (1,(select id from person where name = 'cris'));
-- and works ;)

-- but if we kick the clown, now there is no one to handle the unhapinness what a mess!! what about the check :(!!!
delete from worker where person_id = (select id from person where name = 'the_clown')
```

As you can realize, the check is not beign performing on the deletion of the clown and that is a problem in this example domain model

Comment: Please add a minimal example.

Comment: @McNets done, try to bear with me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`ON DELETE RESTRICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html) ? You can combine this constraint with a function attached to the foreign tables [`CREATE TRIGGER ON DELETE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  foreign_key_id uuid REFERENCES my_foreign_table ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foreign_object_delete()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM my_table 
    WHERE foreign_key_id IS NULL 
    AND foreign_key_id = OLD.foreign_key_id;
    RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER foreign_row_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON my_foreign_table 
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foreign_object_delete();
```

**Update:**
Check a condition in several tables before deleting the record

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foreign_object_delete()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
   IF SELECT exists(SELECT 1 FROM table_x WHERE column_x = 'SAMPLE') THEN
      DELETE FROM my_table 
      WHERE foreign_key_id IS NULL 
      AND foreign_key_id = OLD.foreign_key_id;
   END IF;
      RETURN OLD;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i guess that is not my case... i need to restrict deletion of row under some circunstamces that are not limited to the table itself.

Comment: Through the function you can access any table you want and establish your custom condition check, the function scope is not closed to the table that is attached to with the trigger. @Victor

Comment: please @Imanol .Y can you show me an example where you actually stop the deletion when some circustantes are not beign fullfilled, there is no reference to a foreign table in my case....

Comment: @Victor Just a random query to apply a condition check before deleting a row. You can use any condition or delete statement you want cross-tables.

Comment: Imanol. Y (I can't tag your name btw!) is okey... if it is not to much for ask, would you be so kind of following my updated example and try to adapt your code to my model?

Comment: finally get it, peeking at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-trigger.html, the part it says ' In the case of a before-trigger on DELETE, the returned value has no direct effect, but it has to be nonnull to allow the trigger action to proceed. Note that NEW is null in DELETE triggers, so returning that is usually not sensible. The usual idiom in DELETE triggers is to return OLD.' ... it would be nice (as home assignment :P) to adapt this answer to my model anyway... for now let's mark is a correct.

Comment: Sorry @Victor didnt have time to adapt the example to your last question edit, feel free to edit

Comment: no need to worrie Imanol, thanks for the tip and for the time of writing an answer. Until next question!